# How can I customize a multi-cluster deployment in GKE?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

GCP has released their multi-cluster service GKE extension (with fleet management) described at https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/multi-cluster-services. There are four kinds of resources with this Kubernetes setup:

1. [MultiClusterIngress](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/multi-cluster-ingress#multiclusteringress_spec)
2. [MultiClusterService](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/multi-cluster-ingress#multiclusterservice_spec)
3. [FrontendConfig](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/ingress-configuration#configuring_ingress_features_through_frontendconfig_parameters)
4. [BackendConfig](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/multi-cluster-ingress#cluster_selection)

What I want to know is, what are all the customizations that can be made to each resource in order to customize the deployment. These customizations might be by using the specs, or undocumented annotations not already listed [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/multi-cluster-ingress#annotations).

Some example customizations might include, but are not limited to:

- How can I state a static name for generated load balancers, firewall rules, and NEGs (or at least know how the names are generated)?
- How can I limit the requests per second to my backends?
- How can I disable HTTP to my loadbalancer (not just redirect it to HTTP)?

The more suggestions, the better. There seems to be quite a bit of magic that goes on behind the scenes as suggested in the [Troubleshooting Section](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/troubleshooting-and-ops#to_resource_mappings). It would be great to be able to know how many things are customizable.

I have a fully functioning deployment using the aforementioned resources with fleet management and I'm looking to customize the MCI deployment (beyond the documented annotations and resource specs listed above) with an eye to labeling things more clearly in our GCP deployment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The annotations listed [here][1] are the only ones supported by MCI and MCS.

But to answer your questions:

- How can I state a static name for generated load balancers, firewall rules, and NEGs (or at least know how the names are generated)?
  **You cannot do this. MCI autogenerates the resources for you and you have no control over how things are named**
- How can I limit the requests per second to my backends?
  **Our LoadBalancers doesn't support rate limiting for backends. That's probably going to be possible in the new HTTP LB's based on Envoy but these features are not available for now**
- How can I disable HTTP to my loadbalancer (not just redirect it to HTTP)?
  **That's not possible with MCI. We only support http to https redirect and that's we recommend. The redirect happens are the loadbalancer proxies before traffic hits your backend. This is the recommended way to go in order to provide the best UX to your users. You don't want people to type http://yourwbesite in their browsers and end up with a 404 NOT Found. So you better let the loadbalancer perform the redirect **
  [1]: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/multi-cluster-ingress#annotations